# unable to install car package in r 3.5.2

Tags: r, ubuntu

I am running R 3.5.2 on Ubuntu 18.4 lts and trying to install car package. I am getting bellow error.

[image]

Comment: The error message shows that it isn’t the car package that’s the problem, it’s a dependency, namely lme4.

Answer (score 1):

Please just run

```
sudo apt-get install r-cran-car
```

as the package has been part of Debian and Ubuntu for a decade and a half (maintained by yours truly).  We provide binaries because installation from source is not for everybody.

Comment: The following packages have unmet dependencies:
     r-cran-car : Depends: r-api-3.4
                  Depends: r-cran-pbkrtest but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: r-cran-quantreg but it is not going to be installed
    E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: It's a FAQ. You have a mixup between R 3.4.* and R 3.5.* packages. I suggest you subscribe to `r-sig-debian` (subscribe first, then post) and we can sort it out.

Comment: Actually, when I am trying in Windows with the same version of R, I am not facing any issue. in ubuntu Lme4 and pbkrtest are not getting installed which is causing the problem.

Comment: You are at a minimum confusing _installation from source_ and _installation from binary_ and likely mixing both which is not a good idea.  I can also _guarantee_ you that dependencies with be installaed either way.